# Enzyme shallow rendering: unable to trigger/assert value change when using 'simulate'

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to assert that I can enter text into an input field in my app. In the browser, the expected behaviour occurs, which is that text appears in the input when I select it and start typing. However in my test, instead of returning 'a' as hoped, the expectation receives 'undefined'.

Here's my test:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Search from './search';

describe('Search', () => {

  const wrapper = shallow(<Search />);

  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    shallow(<Search />);
  });

  it('accepts text in an input', () => {
    const input = wrapper.find('input');
    input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'a' } });
    expect(input.props().value).toEqual('a');
  });
});
```

And the implementation:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchText: "Roi"
    };
  }

  inputUpdate (event) {
    this.setState({ searchText: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form>
        <input type="text"
               className="card-search"
               placeholder="Type card name"
               onChange={ this.inputUpdate.bind(this) }
               value={ this.state.searchText }/>
      </form>
    );
  };
};

export default Search;
```

This is driving me crazy and I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Can anyone shed some light on this for me please?

Comment: Try `input.get(0).value`

Comment: Hi dcodesmith - thanks for getting back to me. I assume you meant: `expect(input.get(0).value).toEqual('a');` - that returns the same 'undefined' sadly.

Comment: Trying logging `input.get(0)`. Let's see if there is anything there.

Comment: This is returned: https://gist.github.com/roidriscoll/5d95d1ddc41f68ef7c9ea98179dbdd04

Comment: There is a `props().value` of `"Roi"` in that object

Comment: Apologies, it seems I pasted the wrong version of the implementation in >_< Have updated now.

Comment: Stick this at the bottom constructor `this.inputUpdate = this.inputUpdate.bind(this);` and then change `onChange={ this.inputUpdate.bind(this) }` to `onChange={ this.inputUpdate }`. Then run test again.

Comment: Same result: `Expected value to equal: "a" Received: undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this works but it seems to be the case ...

Change

```
expect(input.props().value).toEqual('a');
```

to

```
expect(wrapper.find('input').props().value).toEqual('a');
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you dcodesmith! Now I need to delve into this and figure out _why_ that works!

Comment: @xiola, could you kindly mark it as the solution, perhaps? :) Also, I just didn't have time to dig into why that worked. I'm sure there is a reason.

Comment: Sorry, S.O. noob. Thanks again!

Comment: That's fine. Welcome to SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `inputUpdate` does not update your component state. Try this:

```
inputUpdate (e) {
    this.setState({
        searchText: e.target.value
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gustavo, I had pasted the wrong version of the implementation. Updated now, the problem is still the same as originally stated though.